# Do I need to use a preposition when using the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Do I need to use a preposition when using the following sentence?

> Do you use (**in**) Facebook?

I mean to ask if I should use the preposition "in" in this sentence.

Comment: Use "in" with **participate**.  Do you *participate in* any online forums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not use the preposition. Just say, "Do you use Facebook?"

A preposition usually indicates a direction or a relationship. "In" can be a direction: "I am going in", or a relationship, "The book is in the box." Neither is applicable here. "Facebook" is the direct object of the verb "use". The person you are asking is not "using" toward Facebook nor is he "using" inside Facebook.

That said, you might ask, "Are you on Facebook?" or "Are you in Facebook?". The difference here is that instead of asking if they are "using" we are asking if they "are", that is, we are now asking for a state of being. You can "be" inside something, but you can't really "use" inside something.

And maybe I need to clarify there that while you can't "use in X", you could "use X in Y". You could ask, "Do you use the such-and-such feature in Facebook?", in the same sense that one could ask, "Do you use the radio in your car?"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I intentionally didn't say: "Are you on Facebook", because it might be that he is on Facebook but doesn't really use it, as I know about few people.